# Displaying Duplex Printing Option with Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to print a bunch of tabs in Duplex in Excel. Ok, fun times.

This needs to be done in VBA, due to a lot of people needing this. More fun times.

Excel doesn't have Duplex printing as an option in VBA (But Access does for some reason).

You can access the option by going to File -> Print -> Page Setup -> Page -> Options -> Print on both sides. Hurray.

However, apparently this only changes one tab at a time, not all of them at once?

Is there a way to print a bunch of Excel workbook sheets in Duplex 3 mode programatically (Being accommodating for multiple printers)? It looks like no. So the next question is - is there a way to pop up the option described above with VBA, to at least make everything automated except the end users need to click on the right duplex setting a bunch?

Thank you

Alternatively, I might be able to change the duplex setting using the Access object model, but I'm stuck fairly early on trying to select the printer, let alone changing any settings.

```
Sub PrinterChangeWithAccess()
Dim AccessObject As Access.Application
Dim Printer_Name As Printer

Set AccessObject = CreateObject("Access.Application")
PrinterName = AccessObject.Dialogs(acDialogPrinterSetup).Show



End Sub
```

This type of problem - needing to use the Access object model from inside of Excel - is a great example of why something like the vba-excel tag should live, but that's a bit off topic....

Comment: Why not use excel option `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show`?

Comment: Huh? That Access code looks like 100% nonsense, the Access application object doesn't have a dialogs collection, and an `acDialogPrinterSetup` constant doesn't exist. If anything, working with printing options in Access is harder than in Excel. See [this MS docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/printing/programmatically-retrieve-printer-capabilities) for code working with printer options in Access, you need to build your own dialogs if you want to allow users to set settings.